# Facebook App not redirecting to log in page

Tags: facebook, redirect, canvas, authentication

When the user is not logged in and goes to apps.facebook.com/my_app_name_here Facebook redirects to a "Use of app "MY APP NAME HERE" has been restricted" page (if I log in first it works fine).

I don't see the request hitting my server at all. Is there anything I have to do on my app settings to get it to work correctly. Games like cityville redirect to the login page correctly and then bring you back to the app page when logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably happening because your app has **restrictions** configured. Check the restrictions in the "Advanced" tab of your app's settings in the [Developer App](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).
When the user is not logged in, Facebook cannot tell if the user is subject to any of your configured restrictions and so must display a message that it is restricted.

For example, if your app is restricted to ages 21 and older, Facebook cannot determine the age of the user until he/she is logged in.

Comment: Thank you, Don! It was an age restriction on my app.